# Phonegap Add Contacts default type 'work' changing to 'other'

Tags: android, email, cordova, contacts

I am currently using phonegap contacts to an android device, 4.1 Xoom Tablet.

Everything is working except that when I place 'work' as a type in the ContactField constructor for an email, and save it , it saves as 'other'.
I tried with 'home' and it saves as home.

I have another piece of code that updates the contact and on the second time , it does save the 'work' email.

The code to add the email is the same so I'm not sure why it is not saving the first time.

Thanks!